# Typo3 ke_search extension Fatal error

Tags: php, search, typo3, fatal-error, typo3-7.6.x

I'm pretty new to Typo3, so sorry if I can't understand what's the problem here.

I installed the extension ke_search and followed (many times!) [the basic and simple instructions given](https://www.typo3-macher.de/en/facetted-search-ke-search/documentation/quick-installation/) to setup it. The indexer works and everything seems just fine, but when I try to check the front end page, an error occours:

> PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView::setTemplateRootPaths() must be of the type array, null given, called in (...)/typo3conf/ext/ke_search/pi2/class.tx_kesearch_pi2.php on line 126 and defined in (...)/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/View/StandaloneView.php line 192

Unfortunately I can't understand the meaning of this. Is there anybody willing to give me some advice. Needless to say I searched the web to find similar errors, to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have included the static template of ke_search in your root page?

Comment: Thank you @Fox. Nope, didn't include it. In the tab "Resources" in the root page I know I can add it, but what's the sintax?

Comment: Ok, added it using the "Template" Info/Modify section. The error is still showing (flushed all the caches...).

Comment: Damn, maybe you could check the templateRootPaths for this plugin. Use the template module again and select the typoscript object browser. After that you can check if "plugin -> tx_kesearch_pi2 -> templateRootPaths" is set.

Comment: Actually, it's not set. Tbh, I'm only seeing tx_news among my plugins, so maybe there's something wrong... I'm going to study and check if I can find a way. Thanl you so much!

Comment: Ok. You are welcome :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with Version TYPO3 Version 7 or 8, try this Code in your TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_kesearch_pi1 {
    templateRootPaths {
        5 = EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Templates/
        }
    partialRootPaths {
        5 = EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        5 = EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        }
}

plugin.tx_kesearch_pi2 {
    templateRootPaths {
        5 = EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }
    partialRootPaths{
        5 = EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        5 = EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}
```

I think, it's a bug...

Comment: Isn't it just that you have to include the static template?

Comment: Adding the Static TypoScript indeed solved this issue for me. All tho the error message says the template path was missing when it actually wasn't missing.